# Error: invalid input syntax for type json in postgreSQL patch request NextJS

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql

I have been at this for hours and haven't been able to narrow down where the problem is.

I have the following PATCH function in a NextJS 13 app, using postgreSQL:

```
export async function PATCH(request: Request) {
  const body = await request.json()
  const {databaseId, boardStatus, updatedTasks} = body;
  console.log(updatedTasks)
  try {
    const query = 'Update boards SET status = $1, tasks = $2 WHERE id = $3';
    const values = [boardStatus, updatedTasks, databaseId];
    const result = await conn.query(query, values);

    return NextResponse.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error('Failed to update task')
  }
}
```

There seems to be a problem with the tasks data. I am getting this error:

```
 length: 242,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: 'Expected ":", but found ",".',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: 'JSON data, line 1: ...se}],\\"description\\":\\"Testing database save\\"}",...\n' +
    "unnamed portal parameter $2 = '...'",
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'jsonfuncs.c',
  line: '646',
  routine: 'json_errsave_error'
```

I keep looking at the data but am not seeing where the problem is. The details seems to say it's looking for ":" but it's getting ","?

Here is the tasks data:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Launch version one",
    "status": "",
    "subtasks": [
      {
        "title": "Launch privately to our waitlist",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "title": "Launch publicly on PH, HN, etc.",
        "isCompleted": false
      }
    ],
    "description": ""
  },
  {
    "title": "Review early feedback and plan next steps for roadmap",
    "status": "",
    "subtasks": [
      {
        "title": "Interview 10 customers",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "title": "Review common customer pain points and suggestions",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "title": "Outline next steps for our roadmap",
        "isCompleted": false
      }
    ],
    "description": "Beyond the initial launch, we're keeping the initial roadmap completely empty. This meeting will help us plan out our next steps based on actual customer feedback."
  }
]
```

If anyone can point out the issue, that would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Oops, turns out the stringified data passed into the api is an array and I was trying to destructure it as an object:

```
const {databaseId, boardStatus, updatedTasks} = body
```

so instead I grabbed the items from the array and passed them into the values array:

```
const databaseId = body[0];
const boardStatus = body[1];
const updatedTasks = body[2];

 const query = 'Update boards SET status = $1, tasks = $2 WHERE id = $3';
 const values = [boardStatus, updatedTasks, databaseId];
 const result = await conn.query(query, values);
```

However, when the body is created with "await request.json(), the value that is returned for the tasks "updatedTasks = body[2]" is invalid JSON. That is where the error is still happening.

I was able to get it to work by stringifying the tasks a second time but it doesn't seem like this should be necessary.

So first I sent the body as JSON data to the PATCH function. Get the body with request.json(), which returns data that has been parsed but pg seems to require json data. Once I stringify the data it works as it should. I find myself thinking there should be a better way. ;-)

```
const values = [boardStatus, JSON.stringify(updatedTasks), databaseId];
```

Comment: Could you paste the value that caused the error? The `tasks` data you showed is valid, but it's not the value your error message refers to. *Expected ":", but found ",".* sounds like somewhere, the value in question is trying to list array elements in an object, like this `{"a","b","c"}`, instead of `["a","b","c"]` or `{"a":"v_a","b":"v_v","c":"v_c"}` (note the outer brackets).

Comment: `{` makes the parser expect a quoted element (a *key*) followed by a colon `:`, then a corresponding *value*. The `[` would allow for each element to be separated by a single comma `,` from the next. The value you pasted doesn't suffer from this: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AoDW0f6M)

Comment: Thanks for the help all. I updated the post. I was able to get it to work. I guess request.json() returns parsed data. So not in json format. Using 'pg' for postgreSQL seems to require json data. So stringifying it again worked. Though not sure if there is a better approach.